# Changing QGIS Data-defined Labels?

Tags: qgis, labeling, editing

QGIS 2.18.1 - I've used data-defined labelling (X,Y,Rotation fields) with earlier versions of QGIS.  I can move and rotate labels OK with 2.18.1 but cannot change the label text.  When I click on the 'Change label' button and select a label on the canvas, the Layer properties screen comes up, but all the fields are greyed out and hence uneditable.

Has anyone else had this problem?

Comment: In QGIS 2.18.2, it is possible to change the text of the label. Although the fields such as _Display_, _Font_ etc are greyed out. You can also use the **Layer styling dock** by clicking the `Layer Labelling Options` from the toolbar or the left-most icon at the top of the Layers Panel.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Joseph.  However when I select Layer Labelling Options, I get a dialog screen which applies to ALL labels in that layer.  I only want to change one label.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Perhaps a bug? Try QGIS 2.18.2 and see if the problem still persists =)

Comment: Installed 2.18.2 but nothing changed.

Answer (score 2):

Works ok here (2.18.2). Some things to check:
- Make sure your layer is set to label using a field alone and not an expression based on a field.
- Make sure your label text field is editable. Try changing values in it in the attribute table and see if they stick when you save the layer.

Comment: The label IS based on an expression.  Does that mean I can't change it by using the data-defined tool? Installed 2.18.2 but still no go.  Am able to effectively change it via the attribute table though.

Comment: Yes - if it's an expression it will be read only in that dialog. You could post a feature request to expose all fields used by the expression in that dialog.

Comment: Not sure I am QGIS-skilled enough to lodge a request.  Perhaps someone who would know how to word it might take it up?